# Textarea not showing hebrew text from mysql

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, textarea, hebrew

I'm trying to return some particular text from mysql into a textarea. Now this text returning from mysql has

```
    collation=utf8_unicode_ci
```

and the charset is set by adding this line in my php file.

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-8-i" />
```

Cant figure out the problem here. Everything looks alright but why is the textarea not showing hebrew text? Instead it shows "???????" - Question marks.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your mysql connection set to UTF8 (SET NAMES 'uft8')? Is your HTML document encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: I'm sorry i dont know how to set a mysql connection to utf8.
Could you please clarify that?

Comment: Your first query after connecting to the database should be `SET NAMES 'uft8'`

Comment: mixing/matching charsets like that will just corrupt things. You should maintain the SAME charset throughout the entire pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the data entry, or retrieval, the MySQL must be configured to accept unicode(UTF-8) data. There are number of ways, you can do this

1. Place this line on the database connection part

   ```
   mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link); //$link is your connection identifier
   ```
2. Run `charset utf8` on CLI
3. Use `SET NAMES 'utf8'` as your first query to the database

---

Moreover, while outputting such data the screen, the html should be configured to understand unicode characters as well. Use

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
```

At the top of the displaying page.

Comment: after putting mysql_set_charset it shows characters that look like
�§��× �� ��×�� ����¤��� ���©���×� ���§�¦��¢�,

Comment: @Prateek, the meta tags, should be the correct one. Use this `<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />`  on the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

Try this set up.

```
    //  encode web page 'utf-8' which holds the input form
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8">

//  Form submit from webpage 
$text = stripslashes($_POST['text']);

//  connect to database         
$db = mysql_select_db("$my_databasename",$conn)
    or die("ERR; Database");

//  setup UTF-8 on pipe 
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $conn);

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");

$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);

// insert to mysql here
```

Remember to encode the web page that displays / returns the output from mysql. It is good practice to declare utf-8 encoding on all web pages by default unless you have other reason not to.